# Creating a list of names base on user input()

Tags: python, list, user-input

I've been trying to find a way to transform users' name inputs into a python list, so I could later process the information. However, since I'm not very experienced, I can't find a way to do such a thing. When I write the code below, the print() output, is only the second letter of the first name, while I actually intend it to be the second name on the list. So, my question is, how can I make it so that each different name is a different element in the list?

```
# Creates a list of the players
players = input("Insert players\n")
list(players)
print(players[1])
```

Comment: `list(players)` is doing absolutely nothing. It does not affect `players`. It returns a list, but you are discarding the returned value. You could do something like `players_list = []`, then for each new player name, `players_list.add(player_name)`. But that's if you entered one name at a time; if you want to enter multiple players, you need to specify the exact input format you're looking for - should they be separated by commas? Commas and spaces? Something else? And then, you'd have to use the `split()` method on the string of player names to turn it into a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `split()` to turn a string into a list of words:

```
players = input("Insert players\n").split()
print(players[1])  # prints the second player name in the list
```

By default `split()` splits on whitespace, but it takes an optional argument that allows you to split on other strings (e.g. `split(",")` to split on commas).